Ludo Game in Android Studio - Pawn Movement Issues on Different Devices
I am currently developing a Ludo game in Android Studio and have run into a significant issue regarding the movement of pawns across different devices.
Project Setup:
I have created a grid using transparent images.
Each image represents a spot on the Ludo board.

Problem:
When I try to move the pawn, its position does not align correctly with the intended spot on the board across different devices. The pawn's position seems to be off, and it does not match the spot location accurately.
Screenshots:
Here are two GIF to illustrate the issue from s24 ulra and moto edge 20 fusion:
Moto Egde 20 fusion

S24 Ultra


Additional Information:
I am using a GridLayout within a ConstraintLayout to position the board and the pawns.
The images for the spots are transparent PNGs.
I am handling pawn movement programmatically by calculating the positions based on the grid.

What I've Tried:
Ensuring the images are correctly aligned within the grid.
Adjusting the layout parameters to see if it fixes the alignment.
Checking for any hardcoded values that might affect the positioning on different screen sizes and resolutions.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. The pawn's position varies significantly across different devices, which impacts the gameplay experience.
Request for Help:
Could anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to ensure consistent positioning of the pawns across different devices? Is there a specific approach or best practice in handling dynamic layouts that can help resolve this issue?
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!
package com.example.imagemovement

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet
import com.example.imagemovement.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var pathform: ImageView
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var gridLayout: GridLayout
    private lateinit var spots: Array<TextView>
    private lateinit var spawnedTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout
    val bluepath= intArrayOf(133,132,131,130,129,143,158,173,188,203,218,217,216,201,186,171,156,141,125,124,123,122,121,120,105,90,91,92,93,94,95,81,66,51,36,21,6,7,8,23,38,53,68,83,99,100,101,103,104,119,118,117,116,115,114,113)
     val yellowPath= intArrayOf( 23,38,53,68,83,99,100,101,102,103,104,119,134,133,132,131,130,129,143,158,173,188,203,218,217,216,201,186,171,156,141,125,124,123,122,121,120,105,90,91,92,93,94,95,81,66,51,36,21,6,7,22,37,52,67,82,97);
 val redpath= intArrayOf(201,186,171,156,141,125,124,123,122,121,120,105,90,91,92,93,94,95,81,66,51,36,21,6,7,8,23,38,53,68,83,99,100,101,102,103,104,119,134,133,132,131,130,129,143,158,173,188,203,218,217,202,187,172,157,142,127)
  val greenpath= intArrayOf(91,92,93,94,95,81,66,51,36,21,6,7,8,23,38,53,68,83,99,100,101,102,103,104,119,134,133,132,131,130,129,143,158,173,188,203,218,217,216,201,186,171,156,141,125,124,123,122,121,120,105,106,107,108,109,110,111)
    val safeSpot= intArrayOf(188,201,122,91,36,23,102,133)
    private  var tag: String="Board"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        try {

            gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.board)
            setHeightOfgridlayout()

            // Ensure GridLayout has children and get the position of the first child
            gridLayout.post {

                var child=gridLayout.getChildAt(0)
                var y = child.width
                var x = child.height;
                pathform = ImageView(this).apply {
                    setImageResource(R.drawable.google_authenticator_icon) // Set your image here
                    layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(x, y)
                }
                val rootLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.main_layout)
                rootLayout.addView(pathform)

                constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_layout)
                Log.d(tag,"height $y widht $x")
                var i= intArrayOf(91,92,93,94,95,96)
               moveImageToSpots(i) // Pass the array of indices

            }
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Log.d("board",e.toString())
        }

    }

    private fun setHeightOfgridlayout() {
        gridLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
            ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                // Remove the listener to prevent it from being called multiple times
                gridLayout.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)

                // Get the width of the GridLayout
                val gridWidth = gridLayout.width

                // Set the height of the GridLayout equal to its width
                val layoutParams = gridLayout.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                layoutParams.height = gridWidth
                gridLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams
            }
        })
    }

    private fun moveImageToSpots(indices: IntArray) {
        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        var currentIndex = 0

        val runnable = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                if (currentIndex < indices.size) {
                    val index = currentIndex
                        val targetSpot = gridLayout.getChildAt(indices[index])
                        val location = IntArray(2)
                        targetSpot.getLocationOnScreen(location)
                        val targetX = location[0]// + targetSpot.width/2 - pathform.width /2
                        val targetY = location[1]// - targetSpot.height/2 - pathform.height/2

                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(pathform, "x", pathform.x, targetX.toFloat()).apply {
                            duration = 500
                            start()
                        }
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(pathform, "y", pathform.y, targetY.toFloat()).apply {
                            duration = 500
                            start()
                        }
                    currentIndex++
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 500) // Delay for animation
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        handler.post(runnable)
    }
    fun Context.getScreenWidthInDp(): Float {
        val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
        val screenWidthPx = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        return screenWidthPx / displayMetrics.density
    }
}


I attempted to determine the precise location of each spot on the Ludo board but was unsuccessful. My goal is to identify the exact position of each block on the board so that it aligns consistently across all Android devices.
